# Java if else in while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

i had this problem where while looping, the output shows the loop **but** the invalid is also there. how do i separate the loop and the if...else statements?

below is the program code.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String option = new String("Y");

while (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
    System.out.println("Good Morning!!");
    System.out.print("Do you want to continue [Y/N]: ");
    option = scan.nextLine();

    if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        break;

    } else {

        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}
```

this is the output of the loop. the invalid is only supposed to show up when i put in a different letter other than y or n

```
Do you want to continue [Y/N]: y
invalid
Good Morning!!
Do you want to continue [Y/N]: y
invalid
Good Morning!!
```

and it was supposed to show like this

```
Good Morning!!
Do you want to continue [Y/N]: y
Good Morning!!
Do you want to continue [Y/N]: y
Good Morning!!
Do you want to continue [Y/N]: n
```

Comment: use `continue`  in else block before `System.out.println`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: You need a case for when option equals "Y".

Answer (score 1):

You're just cheking if it's a "N" but not a "Y" so it'll will show invalid for Y. You just have to add another `else if` and the last `else` with the invalid.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String option = new String("Y");

while (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
    System.out.println("Good Morning!!");
    System.out.print("Do you want to continue [Y/N]: ");
    option = scan.nextLine();

    if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        break;

    }else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
        continue; 
    }else {
        System.out.println("invalid");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Good Morning!!");
    System.out.print("Do you want to continue [Y/N]: ");
    String option = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    if ("N".equals(option))
        break;
    if ("Y".equals(option))
        continue;

    System.out.println("invalid");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what the changes were and why - it's just a code dumb, which isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement `else if` to check for acceptable character and remove the redundant check from the condition in `while`:

```java
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Good Morning!!");
    System.out.print("Do you want to continue [Y/N]: ");
    String option = scan.nextLine();

    if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        break;
    } else if (!option.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}
```